# Bootstrap Toggle checkbox not working every time

Tags: checkbox, toggle, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap toggle checkbox from http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ in a partialview (bootstrap modal window). Inside the partial view, I have reference to the js file (from https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js).

The bootstrap check/uncheck seem to work alternatively. For example, if I open the popup for the first time it works, second time doesn't work, third time works etc.

Is this a known issue and a workaround exists? Can someone please guide? Thanks!

Comment: I encounter this in one of my projects. Using ASP.NET MVC I loaded the required references inside the partial view since we are not allowed to add these in the layout. I hope someone can answer this.